# Json.Net Serialization not providing expected results

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following data model

```
class Tournament{
    int Id { get; set;}
    ICollection<League> Leagues { get; set;}
}

class League{
    int Id {get;set;};
    Tournament Parent { get; set;}
    ICollection<Player> Players { get; set;}
    ICollection<Round>  { get; set;}
}
 class Player{
    int Id  { get; set;}
     League Parent  { get; set;}
     ICollection<Game> Games { get; set;}
 }
 class Round{
    int Id  { get; set;}
    ICollection<Game> Games { get; set;}
    League Parent  { get; set;}
}

class Game{
 int Id { get; set;}
 Player playerOne { get; set;}
 Player playerTwo  { get; set;}
 Round Parent { get; set;}
}
```

Which I am having trouble serializing and deserializing using json.net newtsoft.

I am getting the following file http://myjson.com/11xorf

Using the following JSON net settings

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
            ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto,
        };
```

But as you can see from the output file it is not correct, I would like so that the games store references to the players and games but it is not referencing them correctly. And on desrizaling none of the parent child relationships are being mapped except for league to tournament.

I have no data attributes on any of the classes.

Can anyone advise on what is going wrong? Do I need to change the data model?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show the code you use to create the structure.  It's possible, for example, that you are mistakenly creating new Player objects rather than referencing them.

Comment: Please share code that reproduces the problem, and also explain what is wrong with the linked JSON -- i.e., a [mcve].  The classes you show cannot be the classes used to generate that JSON since Json.NET serializes only public members by default.